# Serializing a class containing a Dictionary of Dictionay

Tags: c#, serialization, javascriptserializer

I have defined a class which contains only one member of type dictionary of dictionary. I want to serialize it to `JSON` format and hence using `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
[Serializable]
class X
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dic;

    public X()
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        this.dic.Add("x", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "a", "b" } });
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new X();
        x.Add();
        string msg = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver()).Serialize(x);
        var y = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver()).Deserialize<X>(msg);
    }
}
```

Now, the above code run successful without any error/exception but the results are not as excepted. The serialized string of class X in the above code is

```
{"__type":"Testing.X, Testing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

Can anybody tell me whats the problem in the above code and what I'm missing? Also, if in the above class, I change the inner dictionary type to `Dictionary<string, IEntity>` then what all I have to do to serialize it.

Comment: What do you get when you don't use `SimpleTypeResolver` ?

Comment: An empty json string i.e. `"{}"`

Comment: Try changing the defintion of *dic* from `private readonly` to `public`

Comment: Ok, now I getting the correct serialize string i.e. `{"__type":"Testing.X, Testing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","dic":{"x":{"a":"b"}}}`

Comment: @L.B: Can you tell me what is the problem in `private readonly` and is it possible to serialize an instance containing `private readonly` type?

Comment: If you use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) you can decorate `dic` with `JsonProperty` attribute and get the desired output without making it public,

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScriptSerializer` is designed to only pull public properties by default.  Once you expose the field through a getter or setter you should be able to serialize this data.

```
[Serializable]
class X
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dic;

    public X()
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        this.dic.Add("x", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "a", "b" } });
    }

    //Property exposing private field 'dic'.
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Dictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return dic;
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new X();
        x.Add();
        string msg = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver()).Serialize(x);
        var y = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver()).Deserialize<X>(msg);
    }
}
```

In this case, the string contains the following output (look to the very end):

```
{"__type":"ConsoleApplication1.X, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","Dictionary":{"x":{"a":"b"}}}
```

Comment: But with only `getter`, you will not be able to *deserialize* it.

Comment: BTW: What do you think JavascriptSerializer does for  *public* fields/properties without using *reflection*?

Comment: @L.B Fair point on reflection.  I obviously need more coffee.